# Function that changes a picture every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I need a function that changes the picture every 3 seconds. Here is my code, it has to be using the case structure, not sure whats wrong, any suggestions?

```
<script>
 "use strict";
  var currentImage = 1;
  var autoAdvance = setInterval(ChangeAd, 3000);

  function ChangeAd() {
  var image = document.getElementsByTagName"img");
     switch(currentImage){
        case 1:
           currentImage = 2;
           return image[o].src = "concert2.gif";
           break;
        case 2:
           currentImage = 3;
           return image[o].src = "concert3.gif";
           break;
        case 3:
           currentImage = 4;
           return image[o].src = "concert4.gif";
           break;
        case 4:
           currentImage = 5;
           return image[o].src = "concert5.gif";
           break;
        case 5:
           currentImage = 1;
           return image[o].src = "concert1.gif";
           break;
     }

  } 
</script>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName"img"); = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

Comment: `[o]` - what is it? Did you mean `[0]`

Comment: @baao I was asking my teacher and I dont know if she meant it to be a number, would it work if that were empty or do I need 0-4?

Comment: You don't show that in your code, I don't know which image you want to set. If you set it to [0] it will set the first image's src though

Comment: you need it to be a number ... depending on how many image tags you have, it could be anywhere from 0 to 1 less than the number of image tags you have - my guess is, it should be 0, because you're asking how to change the picture ... so you'd want to change the same image every time

Comment: pretty sure @JaromandaX covered you problem, but also note that `return` and `break` are redundant. If you are returning, it will never hit the break.

Answer (score 1):

First, this:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName"img")
```

should be this:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("img")
```

Second: `image[o].src` uses the letter `o` and should use the number `0`

Third, the `case` branches don't need to return anything. They just need to set the value counter. `return` is used for two reasons. The first is to simply exit the function and return control to the caller. In your case, the `break` statements already do that, so `return` doesn't help. The second reason for using `return` is to have the function return an overall result to the caller. That's not what you are after here either - - you don't want a value sent back from the function, you just want the function to update the source of the image.

Fourth, there is no need to repeat the setting of the image source. Just set a variable to the right value and then change the source outside of the `switch`.

```js
  "use strict";
  var currentImage = 1;
  var autoAdvance = setInterval(ChangeAd, 3000);
  var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  var source = "";

  function ChangeAd() {
     switch(currentImage){
        case 1:
           currentImage = 2;
           break;
        case 2:
           currentImage = 3;       
           break;
        case 3:
           currentImage = 4;        
           break;
        case 4:
           currentImage = 5;       
           break;
        case 5:
           currentImage = 1;     
           break;
     }
    
     // Once you break out of the matched case branch,
     // you'll wind up here and all you need to do is
     // use the value of your counter to set up the image:
     source = "concert" + currentImage + ".gif";
     image[0].src = source;
     image[0].alt = source;   
  }
```

```html
<img src="someimg.jpg" alt="some image">
```

Comment: And fifth, get rid of the switch block entirely and just increment the variable (using either an `if` or `%` to allow for the 5->1 case)...

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, but if you read the OP, the challenge was to use a `switch`.